# Getting an error while trying to execute a stored procedure loop - MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Getting an error for the following:

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE updateA()
     begin
      DECLARE incr INT Default 1;
      a_loop: LOOP
       update `A_Request` SET `requestRegion` = 
        (SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
        (CASE
        WHEN B_ProductLine.subRegion in (4,5) THEN 108
        WHEN B_ProductLine.subRegion in (6,7) THEN 109
        WHEN B_ProductLine.subRegion in (195,201) THEN 111
        ELSE null
        END) SEPARATOR '; '
        )
        as `newRegion`
        FROM `B_ProductLine` where B_ProductLine.requestId in (Select `A_Request`.bId FROM (SELECT * from `A_Request` where `A_Request`.`id` = incr) as `derived`) group by B_ProductLine.requestId) WHERE `A_Request`.`id` = incr;
    
       SET incr = incr + 1;
       IF incr = 77 THEN
        LEAVE a_loop;
       END IF;
      END LOOP a_loop;
    END $$;
```

This is the error:
"Query was empty".
When running the query on its own outside the stored procedure, I don't run into any issues at all

Comment: For debugging - Before creating procedure test each query individually

Answer (score 0):

You have to end all lines that have a comand with a semicolon and also you missed a DELIMITER at the end

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE updateA()
 begin
  DECLARE incr INT Default 1;
  a_loop: LOOP
   update `A_Request` SET `requestRegion` = 
    (SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
    (CASE
    WHEN B_ProductLine.subRegion in (4,5) THEN 108
    WHEN B_ProductLine.subRegion in (6,7) THEN 109
    WHEN B_ProductLine.subRegion in (195,201) THEN 111
    ELSE null
    END) SEPARATOR '; '
    )
    as `newRegion`
    FROM `B_ProductLine` where B_ProductLine.requestId in (Select `A_Request`.bId FROM (SELECT * from `A_Request` where `A_Request`.`id` = incr) as `derived`) group by B_ProductLine.requestId) WHERE `A_Request`.`id` = incr;

   SET incr = incr + 1;
   IF incr = 77 THEN
    LEAVE a_loop;
   END IF;
  END LOOP a_loop;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```